# Two error messages in a php template with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got 2 error messages after I set up a new wordpress installation & installed the knowledge template. It's the first time for me to setup a wordpress page & template.
I'm not that known in php and i didn't find a solution for this.

So here u can see the error messages live:
https://www.kassen.de/knowledge/knowledge-base/

The Errormessages are:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /homepages/37/d157950258/htdocs/knowledge/wp-content/themes/knowledgepress/template-knowledgebase.php on line 98

and

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /homepages/37/d157950258/htdocs/knowledge/wp-content/themes/knowledgepress/template-knowledgebase.php on line 116

And this is the code from the php files on the specific lines:

Line98:

```
if(count($subcategories)==0 && count($cat_posts)==0){
    continue;
}
```

Line 116:

```
if(count($subcategories)>0) {
    foreach($subcategories as $sub_category) { 
        $term_id[] = $sub_category->term_id;
        ?>
```

Does someone has a solution for this?
This would be awesome!

Greetings :)

Comment: In wordpress, i added 5 categories and for each category 1 contribution.